# chrome driver SessionNotCreatedException: session not created

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to work with Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver ( for now I've tried)

91.0.4472.10100

91.0.4472.1900

when trying to create an instance of chrome driver

```
chromeOptions =
{{
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
  "goog:chromeOptions": {},
  "loggingPrefs": {
    "browser": "WARNING"
  },
  "acceptSslCerts": true,
  "ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS": true
}}

 new ChromeDriver(path, chromeOptions)
```

the chrome driver is crushed and I'm getting a SessionNotCreatedException

my current chrome version is Version 91.0.4472.124

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have latest version of both of them.

I would suggest you to download chrome driver automatically (every time a new version comes)

**Installation :**

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

**Usage**

Just type `import chromedriver_autoinstaller` in the module you want to use chromedriver.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

[Reference link](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/)

Comment: first i'm using c# :) 
but why would it throw this exception ?  , is it related to my chrome version ?.
do i need to prevent auto-updates to my chrome browser ?

Comment: It was not tagged

Comment: have in-line support for both of them.

Comment: I think this issue might be related to my chrome settings, I've tested the same code on my team member laptop, and the code worked. do you know of any chrome settings that might cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i've finally solved my issue...

i had two issues :

1. the chrome was installed on : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
   instead of : C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
2. for this one i don't have an explanation , since the current code works on several team members that had the chrome installed under programfiles.

but when i've added

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
```

to the ChromeDriver the issue was resolved.